# Using JavaScript RegExp to match the first item in a list surrounded by parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string of text I'm trying to parse with RegExp in JavaScript.  Let's say it looks like this:

```
var myString = "This is a string of text (item item item) and more text here.";
```

I need to match the first occurrence of the word '`item`' based on the fact that it is the first item inside the parentheses.  I can't figure out how to write a pattern that will match ONLY the first item inside a set of parentheses.

Some of you may want to think of it like this:  Pretend I'm parsing a string of Lisp and want to match all cars.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you can avoid checking for an opening parenthesis you could use a look ahead for the closing parenthesis.

```
item(?=[^\)]*\))
```

You can also use capturing groups with:

```
\(.*?(item).*?\)
```

*EDIT*

For a word that is repeated somewhere in the parentheses at least once:

```
\(.*?(\b\w+\b).*?\1.*?\)
```

*EDIT 2*

For just the first alphanumeric set of characters in a parentheses:

```
\([^\w]*(\b\w+\b).*?\)
```

Or a simpler alternative:

```
\(.*?\b(\w+)\b.*?\)
```

Comment: That's almost what I need.  The problem is that the words in parentheses won't actually be 'item'.  They will be strings of letters I don't know ahead of time.

Comment: Will you be looking for the first word that is repeated at all times?

Comment: No the first word is unlikely to be repeated but it might be.

Comment: Oh... So you just need the first word in ()?

Comment: @AramKocharyan yes I think so.

Comment: See my edit. If you need a more limited set of characters to define a word, just change the \w (both) to say [a-zA-Z] etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
/\((\w*?)(?:\s|\))/
```

Live example: http://tinkerbin.com/EJyjEX30 (click run to run the code))

Comment: Fails when the string is `'(item)'`

Comment: That does help but the problem is that I'm trying to make a plugin for a lexer someone else has created.  Unless I can make the pattern return only the capture group I'm stuck because I don't have a way to tell the lexer to use a capture group instead of the actual match.

Comment: Check the live example how I get the first group: `myStr.match(/\((\w*?)(?:\s|\))/)[1]`

Comment: Both of these answers work as long as I access capture groups but the problem is that in this particular case, I don't have that.  I guess if that's the case, this may be impossible?

Comment: You are looking for lookbehind? `(?<=H)\w` match a letter after a H. For instance `'Hello'` will match the `'e'`. But unfortunately, JS doens't support lookbehinds...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a pattern that doesn't match the opening parenthesis, since Javascript regexes don't support lookback.

You probably need to update your lexer code to understand capturing groups (or general functions or something convenient...) or you need to restructure you code so that it can deal with that extra paren you can't get rid of.